# Node.Js: Signed cookie can't be found

Tags: node.js, express, cookies

Using a MEAN environment (with express 4), I create a cookie like this.

```
//webserver.js
app.use(cookieParser(„somesecretkey“));

//somescript.js
res.cookie(‚testcookie‘, ‚testvalue', {signed: true, maxAge: 999999, httpOnly: true});
```

In another script, I try to check the existence of the cookie like this.

```
//someotherscript.js
if(req.cookies.testcookie){   
        console.log("COOKIE EXISTS“+req.cookies.testcookie); 
}else{
        console.log(„NO COOKIE“+req.cookies.testcookie); //always undefined
}
```

I checked the browser for the cookie and it definitely exists but the console keeps logging that there is no cookie (cookie undefined) when I press refresh or simply visit the page. As soon as I change the cookie to unsigned and remove the secret key, I can access it!? Why can’t the cookie be found once its signed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [expressjs documentation for res.cookie](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res.cookie) tells us:

> When using [cookie-parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cookie-parser) middleware, this method also supports signed
>   cookies. Simply include the `signed` option set to `true`. Then
>   `res.cookie()` will use the secret passed to `cookieParser(secret)` to
>   sign the value.
>
> ```
> res.cookie('name', 'tobi', { signed: true });
> ```
>
> Later you may access this value through the [req.signedCookie](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#req.signedCookies) object.

So:

- did you specific a secret using `cookieParser`?
- you should check for the cookie in `req.signedCookie`, not `req.cookies`

Comment: That's it! Thanks a lot. No idea how I managed to miss that in the doc. :(